# Is this elliptic integral identity known?

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-functions

Thinking about some physical problem, I came across  the following identity:
$$\phi^2\Pi\left(-\phi,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\phi^{-2}\Pi\left(\phi^{-1},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}+K\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right )=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{8\pi\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2},$$
where $\phi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ is the golden ratio, and
$$K(k)=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2{\theta}}},\quad \Pi(n,k)=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{(1-n\sin^2{\theta})\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2{\theta}}}$$
are complete elliptic integrals of the first and third kind, respectively. Is this identity known?

In fact, more general identity is
$$\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}\Pi\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha-1},k\right)+ \frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}\Pi\left(\frac{1}{\alpha},k\right)=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1-k^2}}+K(k), \tag 1$$
where $\alpha>1$, and
$$k^2=\frac{1}{1+\alpha(\alpha-1)}.$$

P.S. As [მამუკა ჯიბლაძე](https://mathoverflow.net/users/41291/%E1%83%9B%E1%83%90%E1%83%9B%E1%83%A3%E1%83%99%E1%83%90-%E1%83%AF%E1%83%98%E1%83%91%E1%83%9A%E1%83%90%E1%83%AB%E1%83%94) noted (and I have verified it), these are particular cases of [19.7.iii in DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.iii). However I obtained them from an even more general identity:
$$\frac{\alpha+\beta+1}{2\beta}\Pi\left(-\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\beta},k\right)+
\frac{\alpha+\beta-1}{2\alpha}\Pi\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha},k\right)=\\
\frac{1-\alpha+\beta}{1+\alpha-\beta}\Pi(n,k)+K(k), \tag 2$$
where $\alpha\ge 0$, $\beta\ge 0$, $\alpha\ge \beta$, and
$$n=\frac{4(\alpha-\beta)}{(1+\alpha-\beta)^2},\quad k^2=\frac{4(\alpha-\beta)}{(1+\alpha-\beta)^2+4\alpha\beta},$$
in the limit $\alpha-\beta\to 1_-$. Where can I find proof of 19.7.iii in DLMF?

P.P.S. It seems (1) and (2) are valid under more general conditions than indicated. For example, from (2), when $\alpha=-\beta=1/12$, we obtain
$$12\Pi\left(2,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{5}{7}\Pi\left(\frac{24}{49},
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=-K\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)= -
\frac{8\pi\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2},$$
and from (1) then $\alpha=1/2$ we obtain (up to an ambiguity in choosing sign in $\sqrt{-1}=\pm i$)
$$2\Pi\left(2,\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right )+K\left (\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right )=
-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi.$$
At last, when $\alpha=-\beta=-1/12$, (2) gives
$$12\Pi\left (2,i\right)-\frac{7}{5}\Pi\left (-\frac{24}{25},i\right)=K(i)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{4\sqrt{2}\pi}.$$
Wolfram Alpha indicates that all identities are correct.

Comment: Should be a particular case of [19.7.iii](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.iii) in DLMF, no?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that this is the case. However, I obtained it in a different way as a particular case of an even more general identity (see P.S. in the question).

Comment: The most general one looks like it can be somehow derived from [08.03.17.0002.01](https://functions.wolfram.com/08.03.17.0002.01) at the Wolfram functions site.